# Cannot import `Ajv`

Tags: typescript, ajv

when I import Ajv in typescript
get this error in the chrome console!

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './../../node_modules/ajv/dist/ajv.js' does not provide an export named 'default' (at validator.ts:1:8)
```

my code:

```
import Ajv from 'ajv';

import type {JTDSchemaType} from 'ajv/dist/jtd';

import {contactLink} from './type.js';

const ajv = new Ajv();

const contactLinkSchema: JTDSchemaType<contactLink> = {
  properties: {
    header: {type: 'string'},
    link: {type: 'string'},
    description: {type: 'string'},
  },
  optionalProperties: {
    iconName: {type: 'string'},
  },
};

export const contactLinkValidator = ajv.compile(contactLinkSchema);
```

it's occurred in web-dev-server, and it cannot be built in Rollup with the same problem

I checked the ajv problems but it was not resolved!

Comment: Maybe there's an accidental `node_modules` directory in your home directory or some other parent of your project directory?

Comment: @Oblosys no; I install other package and it's working correctly